# I got blank page when I used Storybook for Angular?

Tags: angular, storybook

How could I use storybook for angular?

I followed the main guide but still blank when I choose any component
https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-angular/

[image]

**Updates:**
I convert my angular to use SCSS instead of SASS and it works.
but the `webpack.config.js` in `.storybook` doesn't handle images or fonts.

```
const genDefaultConfig = require('@storybook/angular/dist/server/config/defaults/webpack.config.js');

module.exports = (baseConfig, env) => {
  const config = genDefaultConfig(baseConfig, env);

  // Overwrite .css rule
  const cssRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test && rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/');
  if (cssRule) {
    cssRule.exclude = /\.component\.css$/;
  }

  // Add .scss rule
  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  });

  return config;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Owners of storybook library solved it in version v3.4.0-alpha.5.

The whole issue here:https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/2823

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow webpack config ?

```
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = (storybookBaseConfig, configType) => {
  // configType has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
  // You can change the configuration based on that.
  // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
  storybookBaseConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
  });

  // Return the altered config
  return storybookBaseConfig;
};
```

Comment: it got fix by change sass to scss ad bootstrap to 3 and yes I followed something similar

Comment: how could I handle images and fonts too?